# Web socket and External API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

hope for some advice on what im trying to implement in my app. Basically i have a API where i cant get game matches, rather is basket or soccer.

In my app i need to get the matches available every day, so basically what i did is at midnight i get all the games for today using a cronjob and save it in my database, the data is available i json.

One of the feature that we will implement is live games (json feed is update live), so for example when a match start i need to show the live games and make the results being updated.

Can someone give me a advice the best approach and making it happen the live matches?

Best regards

```
P.S. My app alreay have some time, so im using the Laravel 5.2
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#broadcasting-events

Answer (score 0):

Using **websocket** is the best way if you have to get real time data from the server. Though configuring & using a websocket is not an easy job compared to normal programming but your application would be maintainable by that way. So for the real time data applications, my advice is to use websocket.